# Get all documents by year and month in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I'd like know whether in mongodb exists a way to get this without use aggregate operation because I know that this function has more purposes and I'm not sure that would be correct(Am I wrong?). I've been searching anything simpler like in SQL for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE YEAR(createdDate) = 2018 AND MONTH(createdDate) = 1
```

I am using spring boot with spring data mongodb:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String>{

     @Query("{query}")
     List<Customer> findByCustomQuery();

}
```

Thanks for their answers.

Comment: What is your mongo version ? It is only possible in 3.6 to use find query for your use case.

Comment: Yes, my version is 3.6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) ( 3.6 mongo version operator ) to use aggregation functions in regular query for date units comparisons.

```
@Query("{$expr:{$and:[{$eq:[{$year:'$createdDate'}, ?0]}, {$eq:[{$month:'$createdDate'}, ?1]}]}")
List<Customer> findByCustomQuery(into year, int month);
```